# Ibatis and SQL TimeStamp

Tags: java, sql, db2, ibatis

I have a SQL with a where clause generating this error message :

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.co: A statement contains a use of a parameter marker 
that is not valid.. SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, DRIVER=3.53.70
```

Where clause :

`TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(#startDate#,'00.00.00') and TIMESTAMP(#endDate#,'23.59.59')`

I would like to know if it is possible to insert `#startDate` inside `TIMESTAMP` function.

Comment: This is solved :

TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('$startDate$','00.00.00') and TIMESTAMP('$endDate$','23.59.59')

Comment: Maybe you can add your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: Also, usually try to make these kind of range checks comparisons as lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive (that is, `:inputParameter >= lowerBound` and `:inputParameter < upperBound`).  This will make things like that ending timestamp a little easier to deal with; you're not currently including microseconds, so you're actually going to miss all events at the tail end of a day, _every_ time (they'll default to 0, I believe, but definitely not `999999`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is solved : TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('$startDate$','00.00.00') and TIMESTAMP('$endDate$','23.59.59') – xam7766 Dec 12 '11 at 14:15